# Do I need a framework to use dependency injection?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

I want to start practising dependency injection in C++ to make my code more testable, however after some googling I found articles which say I must use some framework for dependency injection. Is it so? Why does one need such a framework? Why can't I inject dependencies either by subclassing and passing dependencies in constructor by reference or pointer or by passing the class I want to use as dependency as template parameter?

Comment: "subclassing and passing dependencies in constructor by reference or pointer" - assuming I understood this correctly, we do a lot of this. Works perfectly well.

Comment: No. Why would one need a framework? Don't the articles explain these claims?

Comment: Which articles make these claims?

Comment: My guess is that the article you've read was written by an author of such a framework. :)
No you don't *need* such a framework. There are frameworks for this, but it's not something you *must* have, you can easily write your own framework.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, actually it was one article, and  if you don't want to use a framework, it shows how to build a few godawful macros and other code to use for dependency injection.

Comment: Well, ignore that and google for some other DI examples.

Comment: An example of such article - http://ledentsov.de/2013/12/26/quest-for-a-cpp-dependency-injection-container-library-part-1-wallaroo-introduction/

Comment: DI frameworks originate from "managed" world, the world of the large-scale business software. They are Okay with trading off runtime performance for programmers performance and maintainability. DI allows to avoid boilerplate code (let's admit, passing dependencies into constructors is really boring), to speed up development, to improve testability and to avoid many troubles of large codebases. You can write Java in C++ too, but it's probably not the way it was meant by Bjarne. But who knows, Java brought us unit testing, maybe some day DI will become as popular in C++ as it is in Java now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency Injection is a software design pattern which allows you to avoid dependencies to concrete classes. A Dependency container has the responsibility of object creation and to pass/inject dependencies into dependent objects. If you use a DI container your application delegates the responsibility of composing your object graph to a separate service. It provides the infrastructure to create your application in a consistent way and it forces conventions (especially interesting when you want to reuse it in different projects/teams and to force a consistent way to construct the object graph).

Poor-man's DI (e.g. constructor injection: passing a parameter by reference to constructor) is a valid way to do dependency injection.

// Edit: A DI-container also manages the lifecycle of your objects/services.